# Excessive difference in realm file size when storing different NSData

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, realm

I am currently working on an iOS project in Swift and I use Realm for my database.
I am storing a Realm object with one of its attributes being an NSData object (actually it is a UIImage that I converted into NSData).

My problem is pretty simple to understand : when i store an NSData object which size is 3 Mo, my Realm file size is around 15 Mo. But when my NSData object size is 6 Mo, my Realm file size turn to about 80 Mo.

Did anyone experience this issue ?
Is there any reason for this difference ?
Is there any way to fix that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm file size is not equal to the size of the data that is stored for some reasons.

One is internal versions of data.

> If your Realm file is much larger than you expect, it may be because you have a RLMRealm that is referring to an older version of the data in the database.
>
> In order to give you a consistent view of your data, Realm only updates the active version accessed at the start of a run loop iteration. This means that if you read some data from the Realm and then block the thread on a long-running operation while writing to the Realm on other threads, the version is never updated and Realm has to hold on to intermediate versions of the data which you may not actually need, resulting in the file size growing with each write. The extra space will eventually be reused by future writes, or may be compacted — for example by calling writeCopyToPath:error: .

https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/#file-size--tracking-of-intermediate-versions

Also,

> on mobile platforms, Realm file size start at 4KB and double in size every time more than the current allocation is required. This doubling stops at 32MB, at which point the file grows in increments of 16MB. So 16MB -> 32MB -> 48MB.

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/2631#issuecomment-145566190

That's why the file size is larger than you expected.

To optimize (to remove all free space) Realm file size, you can use `writeCopyToPath:error:` method. The copied file will be compacted.